# Writing a chucksum to pdf changes a checksum of the pdf. How to chalange this

Tags: node.js, pdf, checksum

It is common to print a checksum on pdf file to check if the file is the one I want tu use.

I'm buiding a node/puppeteer app to generate a pdf submition - a set of according data save to a database as well.
Then an operater gets the pdf file and imports to the app and app is suppoused to validate the checksum.

But, I try, as many apps do, to print a checksum on a pdf that user don't send an old file.
But I got stuck. To calculate a checksum of a file (md5) I need the file, then I print this checksum  on a file ... it chandes the checksum...

How to overcome?

Comment: Have you tried [md5-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5-file) library? Of course, if the file is modified, the checksum will be different everytime.

Comment: You simply have to inject the checksum in some placeholder which you ignore when calculating the checksum.